# how to cancel jtextarea event?

Tags: java, c#, swing, events

here is the scenario. I've a jtextArea in my project. On keypressed event of jtextArea I check whether pressed key is valid or not by using `getKeyChar()` method of `KeyEvent`. If character is valid character(according to my conditions) then it should be inserted otherwise it shouldn't be. I've searched but I couldn't find a way to cancel the event in case character is invalid. In `C#` this is possible but in `java` is there any way to cancel the event so that character isn't inserted in jtextarea?

here is some simple code using `evt.consume()` but it's not working

```
private void txtArea1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    

        evt.consume();
        return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `KeyListener`s with text components,   There is no guarantee in what order the events may be triggered, so the key may already have updated the underlying `Document` by the time your listener is notified.

It also doesn't deal with what happens when the user pastes text into the field or the field is update by the program

Instead, use a `DocumentFilter`, which is doesn't to allow to filter out content been pushed to the components underlying `Document` model

See [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)

Answer (score 1):

End your event handler with

```
event.consume()
```

[event.consume() docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/event/Event.html#consume%28%29)